# C++ Comparator Not Working

Tags: c++, opensg

I'm trying to sort a set of OpenSG points by their x coord within a set, but it doesn't seem to be working.

My comparator:

```
struct less_than_x {
    inline bool operator() (const OSG::Pnt3f& p1, const OSG::Pnt3f& p2) {
        return (p1.x() < p2.x());
    }
};
```

My code:

```
std::set<OSG::Pnt3f, less_than_x> positions3D; 

OSG::GeoPnt3fPropertyRefPtr pos = OSG::GeoPnt3fProperty::create();

pos->addValue(OSG::Pnt3f(1,2,3));
pos->addValue(OSG::Pnt3f(5,2,1));
pos->addValue(OSG::Pnt3f(4,4,2));
pos->addValue(OSG::Pnt3f(6,4,0));
pos->addValue(OSG::Pnt3f(3,5,1));

// Remove the Z Axis from all of the points
for(OSG::UInt32 i = 0; i < pos->size(); i++)    {        
    OSG::Pnt3f p;              
    pos->getValue(p,i);
    OSG::Pnt3f p2 = OSG::Pnt3f(p.x(), p.y(), 0);
    positions3D.insert(p2);
}

for (std::set<OSG::Pnt3f>::iterator it = positions3D.begin(); it != positions3D.end(); it++) {
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

When printing out the set of points, they are still not in order.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

vershov answer seems to work somwhat for me, but when changing it to double and using this set of points it fails.

```
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(-1, 0, 0));
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(-0.850651, -0.309017, 0));
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(-0.850651, 0, 0));
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(-0.525731, 0, 0));
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(-0.525731, 0.809017, 0));
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(-0.525731, 0.5, 0));
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(-0.447214, 0.525731, 0));
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(-0.447214, 0.850651, 0));
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(-0.447214, 0, 0));
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(-1.05104e-007, 0.309017, 0));
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(-7.00695e-008, 0.809017, 0));
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(0, 1, 0));
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(7.00695e-008, 0.809017, 0));
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(1.05104e-007, -0.309017, 0));
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(0.447214, 0, 0));
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(0.447214, 0.850651, 0));
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(0.447214, 0.525731, 0));
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(0.525731, 0.5, 0));
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(0.525731, 0.809017, 0));
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(0.525731, 0, 0));
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(0.850651, 0, 0));
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(0.850651, 0.5, 0));
positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(1, 0, 0));
```

These are sorted in this order:

```
-1, 0, 0
-0.850651, -0.309017, 0
-0.850651, 0, 0
-0.525731, 0, 0
-0.525731, 0.809017, 0
-0.525731, 0.5, 0
-0.447214, 0.525731, 0
-0.447214, 0.850651, 0
-0.447214, 0, 0
-1.05104e-007, 0.309017, 0
-7.00695e-008, 0.809017, 0
0, 1, 0
7.00695e-008, 0.809017, 0
1.05104e-007, -0.309017, 0
0.447214, 0, 0
0.447214, 0.850651, 0
0.447214, 0.525731, 0
0.525731, 0.5, 0
0.525731, 0.809017, 0
0.525731, 0, 0
0.850651, 0, 0
0.850651, 0.5, 0
1, 0, 0
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out the elements before you insert them into the set?

Comment: [OT]: Note that with you comparator, if you have 2 entries with same `x`, the second one will be discarded as `std::set` will consider `{x, 2, 3}` and `{x, 42, 42}` equivalent.

Comment: The last order looks sorted for x. What am I missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following code:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

struct Pnt3f {
        Pnt3f(int x, int y, int z) : m_x(x), m_y(y), m_z(z) {}
        int x() const { return m_x; }
        int y() const { return m_y; }
        int z() const { return m_z; }
private:
        int m_x;
        int m_y;
        int m_z;
};

struct less_than_x {
    inline bool operator() (const Pnt3f& p1, const Pnt3f& p2) {
        return (p1.x() < p2.x());
    }
};

int main() {

        std::set<Pnt3f, less_than_x> positions3D;

        positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(1,2,0));
        positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(5,2,0));
        positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(4,4,0));
        positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(6,4,0));
        positions3D.insert(Pnt3f(3,5,0));

        for (std::set<Pnt3f>::iterator it = positions3D.begin(); it != positions3D.end(); ++it) {
                std::cout << "(" << it->x() << ", " << it->y() << ", " << it->z() << ")" << std::endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

The output is as following:

```
./a.out 
(1, 2, 0)
(3, 5, 0)
(4, 4, 0)
(5, 2, 0)
(6, 4, 0)
```

So, comparator works as expected and do sort. You need to print out values before line to understand what is going wrong.

```
positions3D.insert(p2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That has fixed it for those test points, but once I try it with large doubles it starts to fail, for example I've changed the struct to use double rather than int and inserted these points (edited original question)

Comment: @jmahony: I don't see where the result order (with `double`) is incorrect. (I'm surprised that the 'duplicated' x are still present thought).

Comment: Could you please provide with sample of "large doubles" that brakes the order?